# Realm Recyclerview Adapter is showing error for edit and delete option

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm, android-cardview, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to implement a simple to-do list application. I used Realm as a local database here. Into cardview item in recyclerview, I have created Taskname, task date on the left and check, delete option on the right. Now the the first problem is when I click on check option or delete option the App crashes with showing one error message that

**Edited Adapter Class**

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Task, TaskAdapter.TaskHolder> {
public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

private Realm realm;

public interface TaskListener {

}

private final TaskListener taskListener;
private final Context context;

public TaskAdapter(TaskListener taskListener, RealmResults<Task> realmResults, Context context) {
    super(realmResults, true);
    this.taskListener = taskListener;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new TaskHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_task_list_layout, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Task task = getData().get(position);
    holder.taskTextView.setText(task.getName());
    holder.doneCheckBox.setChecked(task.isDone());
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    final Date date = (task.getDate());
    if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(0))))
        holder.dateTextView.setText("Today");
    else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(-1))))
        holder.dateTextView.setText("Yesterday");
    else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(1))))
        holder.dateTextView.setText("Tomorrow");
    else if (date.getTime() < getDate(6).getTime()) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        holder.dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar.getTime()).toString());
    } else
        holder.dateTextView.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddTaskActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_POSITION, position);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    holder.doneCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Task task = new Task();
            task.setId(getTask(position).getId());
            task.setDate(getTask(position).getDate());
            task.setName(getTask(position).getName());
            task.setDone(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
            updateTask(position, task);
        }
    });

    holder.deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getTask(position).isDone()) {
                removeTask(position);
                return;
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete?");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete the task you created?");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    removeTask(position);
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}

public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public CardView cardView;
    public TextView taskTextView;
    public TextView dateTextView;
    public ImageView deleteImageView;
    public CheckBox doneCheckBox;

    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        taskTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_tv_name);
        dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_tv_date);
        deleteImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_iv_delete);
        doneCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_cb_done);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}

private Date getDate(int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

protected Task getTask(int position) {
    return getData().get(position);
}

protected void updateTask(int position, Task task) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Task newTask = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
    newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
    newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
    newTask.setName(task.getName());
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

protected void removeTask(int position) {
    Task newTask = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", getTask(position).getId()).findFirst();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    newTask.deleteFromRealm();
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

}

**Edited Activity Class**

```
    public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskAdapter.TaskListener{

    private static final int ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int EDIT_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private Realm realm;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TaskAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ToDo List");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_ll_task);

        setUpRecycler();

        // Variables

        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        // Views
        FloatingActionButton addFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_fab_add);
        //Listeners
        addFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTaskActivity.class), ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAdapter() {

        adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, realm.where(Task.class).findAllSortedAsync("name"),this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setUpRecycler() {

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        setAdapter();
    }
}
```

**Edited AddActivity Class**

```
public class TodoAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variables
    private Context mContext;

    private Realm realm;
    private TodoModel task;
    private Button button;
    private EditText mTaskNameEditText;
    private EditText mTaskDateEditText;
    private EditText mTaskTimeEditText;

String time;
    //private static List<TodoModel> tasks;

    public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
    public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.todo_add_layout);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mContext = this;
        realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        setUpUIViews();
        showData();

        final int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(INTENT_KEY_POSITION, -1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TodoModel.ID == -1)
                    addTask();
                else
                    editTask(position);
            }
        });
        mTaskDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                datePicker(view);
            }
        });
        mTaskDateEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    datePicker(view);
            }
        });
        mTaskTimeEditText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                timePicker( view );
            }
        } );
        mTaskTimeEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    timePicker( view );
            }
        });
        if (position != -1) {
            fillTask(getTask(position)); //how can i modify this line
            button.setText("EDIT");
        }

    }
    private void setUpUIViews() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_bt_add);
        mTaskNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_name);
        mTaskDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_date);
        mTaskTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_add_task_et_time);
    }

    public void showData(){

        RealmResults<TodoModel> tasksResult = realm.where(TodoModel.class).findAll();

    }

    private void fillTask(TodoModel task) {
        mTaskNameEditText.setText(task.getName());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        mTaskDateEditText.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
        mTaskTimeEditText.setText(task.getTime());
    }

    private void addTask() {
        String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
        if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
            mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
        if (task == null) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
            return;
        }
        task.setDone(false);
        addTask(task);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    protected void addTask(TodoModel task) {

        realm.beginTransaction();
        TodoModel newTask = realm.createObject(TodoModel.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setTime(task.getTime());
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(newTask);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
    }
    private void editTask(int position) {
        String taskName = mTaskNameEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskDate = mTaskDateEditText.getText().toString();
        String taskTime = mTaskTimeEditText.getText().toString();
        if (taskName.length() == 0 || taskName.equals("")) {
            mTaskNameEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskDate.length() == 0 || taskDate.equals("")) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        if (taskTime.length() == 0 || taskTime.equals("")) {
            mTaskTimeEditText.setError("Should be filled");
            return;
        }
        TodoModel task = getTask(taskName, taskDate,taskTime);
        if (task == null) {
            mTaskDateEditText.setError("Not a correct date");
            return;
        }
        task.setId(getTask(position).getId());
        updateTask(position, task);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }

    protected void updateTask(int position, TodoModel task) {

        realm.beginTransaction();
        TodoModel newTask = realm.where(TodoModel.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }


    private void datePicker(final View view) {
        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int monthOfYear = currentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dayOfMonth = currentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
                ((EditText) view).setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        mDatePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
        mDatePickerDialog.show();
    }
    private void timePicker(final View view) {
        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(mContext,0, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                mTaskTimeEditText.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
            }
        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
        mTimePicker.show();

    }


    private TodoModel getTask(String name, String dateString,String time) {
        TodoModel task = new TodoModel();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            task.setName(name);
            task.setDate(sdf.parse(dateString));
            task.setTime(time );
            task.setDone(false);
            return task;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            onBackPressed();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public class TaskCompare implements Comparator<TodoModel> {
        @Override
        public int compare(TodoModel o1, TodoModel o2) {
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have a `private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();` in your adapter even though you shouldn't. You're supposed to use `getData()`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but it again show the error for this line  protected Task getTask(int position) {
        return tasks.get(position);
    },

Comment: 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at realmtest.com.to_do_list_test.activity.TaskAdapter.getTask(TaskAdapter.java:154)

Comment: You shouldn't even have a field called `tasks`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Could you plaese explain based on my code, it would be really nice, because, I am still learning. and may be  there are lots of error in writing the code

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If I remove tasks, then I get error for getTask, update task and remove task

Comment: That's because none of those methods should be touching `tasks` either. As I said,`tasks` should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Task, TaskAdapter.TaskHolder> {
    public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
    public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

    private Realm realm;

    public interface TaskListener {

    }

    private final TaskListener taskListener;
    private final Context context;

    public TaskAdapter(TaskListener taskListener, RealmResults<Task> realmResults, Context context, Realm realm) {
        super(realmResults, true);
        this.taskListener = taskListener;
        this.context = context;
        this.realm = realm;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new TaskHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_task_list_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Task task = getData().get(position);
        holder.taskTextView.setText(task.getName());
        holder.doneCheckBox.setChecked(task.isDone());
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

        final Date date = (task.getDate());
        if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(0))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Today");
        else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(-1))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Yesterday");
        else if (sdf.format(date).equals(sdf.format(getDate(1))))
            holder.dateTextView.setText("Tomorrow");
        else if (date.getTime() < getDate(6).getTime()) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            holder.dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE", calendar.getTime()).toString());
        } else
            holder.dateTextView.setText(sdf.format(task.getDate()));
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddTaskActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_KEY_POSITION, position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        holder.doneCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Task task = new Task();
                task.setId(getTask(position).getId());
                task.setDate(getTask(position).getDate());
                task.setName(getTask(position).getName());
                task.setDone(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
                updateTask(position, task);
            }
        });

        holder.deleteImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getTask(position).isDone()) {
                    removeTask(position);
                    return;
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Delete?");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to delete the task you created?");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        removeTask(position);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CardView cardView;
        public TextView taskTextView;
        public TextView dateTextView;
        public ImageView deleteImageView;
        public CheckBox doneCheckBox;

        public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            taskTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_tv_name);
            dateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_tv_date);
            deleteImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_iv_delete);
            doneCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_task_list_cb_done);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        }
    }

    private Date getDate(int day) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, day);
        return calendar.getTime();
    }

    protected Task getTask(int position) {
        return getData().get(position);
    }

    protected void updateTask(int position, Task task) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Task newTask = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", task.getId()).findFirst();
        newTask.setDate(task.getDate());
        newTask.setDone(task.isDone());
        newTask.setName(task.getName());
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    protected void removeTask(int position) {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Task newTask = realm.where(Task.class).equalTo("id", getTask(position).getId()).findFirst();
        newTask.deleteFromRealm();
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskAdapter.TaskListener {    
    private static final int ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int EDIT_TASK_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;

    private Realm realm;

    public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
    public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TaskAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ToDo List");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_ll_task);

        setUpRecycler();

        // Views
        FloatingActionButton addFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_tasks_fab_add);
        //Listeners
        addFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddTaskActivity.class), ADD_TASK_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setAdapter() {    
        adapter = new TaskAdapter(this, realm.where(Task.class).findAllSortedAsync("date"),this, realm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void setUpRecycler() {
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // use a linear layout manager since the cards are vertically scrollable
        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        setAdapter();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class AddTaskActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Variables
private Context mContext;

private Realm realm;

private Button button;
private EditText mTaskNameEditText;
private EditText mTaskDateEditText;

public final static String INTENT_KEY_POSITION = "position";
public final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MMM/yy";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_task);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Add Task");

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mContext = this;
    realm=Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    setUpUIViews();
    showData();

    final int position = getIntent().getIntExtra(INTENT_KEY_POSITION, 0);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == -1)
                addTask();
            else
                editTask(position);
        }
    });
    mTaskDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            datePicker(view);
        }
    });
    mTaskDateEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            if (b)
                datePicker(view);
        }
    });
    if (position != -1) {
        fillTask(getTask(position));
        button.setText("EDIT");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code inQuestion still I am getting error. I have mentioned the error in question.

Comment: Right. Realm instance should be given to adapter.

Comment: Where can I modify this line?

Comment: THe app is not crashing now, also I can check anddelete. Bubt I am having the second problem which I have mentioned in my question. If I edid one item, it is not set in correct postion and if I click any of the item to go to edit activity, either it si showing the previous one or the next one. Evrything was ok just before editiong an item. But after doing one edit the list become unmanaged.

Comment: You need to be more specific what you mean. The code I provided should always sort itself according to date.

Comment: Just now I noticed that delete option sometimes work and sometimes showing the error which I have mentioned below the code in question.

Comment: @EpicPanada. the another problem is when I click an item for edit it is shoing the wrong item, may be the pprevious one or the next one. Foor example if I click task 4 it is shoing task 5,

Comment: oh, that's because you're sending `position` between your activities instead of `id`

Comment: Panad, in which line I am sending position. could you please explain more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153353/discussion-between-ktina-and-epicpandaforce).

Comment: THis is still crashing for sometimes when I click delete button. Could plaese tell me in which case should I modify the activity class.

Comment: ... You're sending it in the intent to AddTaskActivity, from the adapter.... BTW if there is still a crash, then add the stack trace to the question

Comment: Yes. I am sending the intent to add Task activity. After creating 3 or4 task, when I edit one item it never update to same place. it shows some wrong item after that. How can I modify my Activity class?

Comment: Send the task ID and query object from the Realm instead of hacking with position

Comment: @EpicPanada I have modified my AddActivity. Could you please have a look. I still in confustion in some cases how can I modify this. How can I set Id instead of tasks. I have modified add task and update task in my update code